# Ubuntu Server Blinking Cursor after Fresh Install

Tags: boot, server, grub2

Ubuntu Newbie here,

I am installing Ubuntu Server 14 on an SSD on a Lenovo ThinkCentre, and every time I install completely, I receive the dreaded blinking cursor. But, here is the kicker, if I put in the media I used to install Ubuntu Server with, and select from the BIOS Boot Options menu to start-up to the install Media, it runs Ubuntu Server with no problems.

I reinstalled Ubuntu on the SSD twice now, and I even explicitly noted that GRUB Boot Loader be installed on the SSD. But, I cannot, for the life of me, boot the machine up to Ubuntu Server without having to select the Ubuntu Server Install Media to boot to via BIOS.

I should also note that there are no other HDD/SSDs running off of the motherboard, and I am not dual-booting. I am running Ubuntu Server strictly and fully off of one SSD.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: First, as you have booted and see the 'blinking cursor': Hold `CTRL`+`Alt` and hit `F1` - if that does give you a `Login:` then do login and have a go: 1) looking through contents of *.log files in `/var/log` and 2) the output of `dmesg`. I'm not sure if I will be able to help you out - but that should be a start for further analysis. In hope you're confident with using the shell... :-]

Comment: @Hannu: I unfortunately couldn't get to this menu, but I fixed the issue. See answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue, by accessing the command line/terminal and just re-installing GRUB. I am guessing that there was an issue with the install media to where it didn't install GRUB properly. But, I got it to work! :) Thanks for the help all!

Comment: Ahh... you never saw a grub menu or there was something wrong with it. Ok.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Tried on different hardware with the same result. Even the grub installer wouldn't fix the issue. Here is what did fix the issue:

When the grub installer started, it automatically selected /dev/sda (usb drive). There was no option to change the drive. I pulled out the usb drive and ran the grub installer which selected /dev/sdb (hard drive). Everything worked great after this. I now always pull the usb drive when the installer gets to the grub part.